# using SOAP web service in back-end with C#

Tags: c#, soap

I am so new in SOAP in backend with c# and need help:
I am a young(new) web developer in backend with c#, I have to write a backend for a project with already in the References of project, all SOAP has been injected AND the frontend is with Angular(from my college).
SO my problem is How can I access and work with this SOAP and match it methodes with frontend part, I am completely confused, Please guide me with tutorial or article ...

Comment: While that is a great question, unfortunately StackOverflow is not the right site for this kind of question. We are better suited for questions where you have written some code and have issues with it (as opposed to suggesting tutorials / articles etc).

Comment: If you write the backend why not transform the SOAP to JSON/REST what is more suitable for javascript frontends like Angular.